# tom cat starts but html doesn't load

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 box and i have started tomcat server on the same. I can see in the logs that the server has started. I can also telnet into localhost and can get the html as shown below. But when i try to get the same in browser by "http:ec2-*****:9000/ then it doesn't respond. I created my instance using the default settings. Is it because of some kind of firewall?

```
ubuntu@ip-10-250-38-240:~/apprickwebapp$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.


GET http://localhost/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>It works !</h1>

<p>If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!</p>

<p>This is the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at     <code>/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html</code></p>

<p>Tomcat7 veterans might be pleased to learn that this system instance of Tomcat is installed with <code>CATALINA_HOME</code> in <code>/usr/share/tomcat7</code> and     <code>CATALINA_BASE</code> in <code>/var/lib/tomcat7</code>, following the rules from     <code>/usr/share/doc/tomcat7-common/RUNNING.txt.gz</code>.</p>

<p>You might consider installing the following packages, if you haven't already done so:</p>

<p><b>tomcat7-docs</b>: This package installs a web application that allows to browse the Tomcat 7 documentation locally. Once installed, you can access it by clicking <a href="docs/">here</a>.</p>

<p><b>tomcat7-examples</b>: This package installs a web application that allows to access the Tomcat 7 Servlet and JSP examples. Once installed, you can access it by clicking <a href="examples/">here</a>.</p>

<p><b>tomcat7-admin</b>: This package installs two web applications that can help managing this Tomcat instance. Once installed, you can access the <a href="manager/html">manager webapp</a> and the <a href="host-manager/html">host-manager webapp</a>.<p>

<p>NOTE: For security reasons, using the manager webapp is restricted to users with role "manager". The host-manager webapp is restricted to users with role "admin". Users are defined in <code>/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml</code>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open port 9000 in the security group that is assigned to that instance. On the AWS EC2 console, go to security groups on the left, select the group applied to that instance, at the bottom, select the tab "inbound", port range "9000", Source "0.0.0.0/0".

Then "add rule" and "apply rule change". That'll allow you inbound to port 9000 after a short time.